# sbt publish local: Undefined resolver 'local'

Tags: scala, sbt, ivy

When trying to `publish-local` in sbt, I get the following output:

```
[info] :: delivering :: com.mycompany#util_2.9.1;0.1.0-SNAPSHOT :: 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT :: integration :: Tue Jan 15 11:23:01 CET 2013
[info]  delivering ivy file to /Users/martink/code/my-project/util/target/scala-2.9.1/ivy-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.xml
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last my-util/*:publish-local for the full output.
[error] (my-util/*:publish-local) Undefined resolver 'local'
```

I suspect this is because of some settings in my build file because publish-local works on fresh projects. Any ideas on how to make `publish-local` work again?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We found out the problem was caused by overriding `external-resolvers`:

```
val myRepo = "my-public" at "http://my-nexus-server/content/groups/public/" 
externalResolvers := Seq(publicRepo)
```

We did this to exclude the default Maven central repository from our resolvers. This, however, also removed the *local* resolver that is used by `publish-local`.

The solution was to add the local resolver back:

```
val ivyLocal = Resolver.file("local", file(Path.userHome.absolutePath + "/.ivy2/local"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
externalResolvers := Seq(ivyLocal, myRepo)
```

Another solution would be to not override `externalResolvers` but just disable Maven central.

```
resolvers := Seq(myRepo)
externalResolvers <<= resolvers map { rs =>
  Resolver.withDefaultResolvers(rs, mavenCentral = false)
}
```

Once you `publish-local`, Ivy seems to give preference to the local snapshot version over remote snapshot versions. To have your published artifact picked up by another project, just run `sbt compile` in that project (seems like `sbt update` is not even necessary).

See also http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html

Comment: You might also be interested in overriding repositories at the user-level: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Proxy-Repositories.html.